# How to minimize a quasi-convex function in 2 dimensions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, disciplined-quasiconvex-programming

I know that if $f$ is a quasi-convex function in one dimension (that is, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$), then we can use the 'golden section' line search to find the optimizer.

Now suppose I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is quasi-convex. I seek to minimize $f$. We can assume that we are initially given a bounded axis-aligned rectangle which is guaranteed to contain the minimizer.

Is there an analogy to line search in 2D which I can use to minimize this function?

Comment: By "optimize" do you mean maximize or minimize?

Comment: Oh right, I changed it to minimize. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your problem of interest is, but are you familiar with the Bisection method for quasiconvex optimization, as explained in section 4.2.5 "Quasiconvex optimization" of Boyd and Vandenberghe "Convex Optimization" https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf ?

Comment: This is a useful resource. But I don't understand how to practically use his method. Given my quasi-convex function $f$, how can I obtain the functions $\phi_t$ which are required to use the bisection method?

Comment: Did you read section 3.4.5, as was referenced in section 4.2.5? Perhaps you can actually shows us the quasiconvex function of interest, then more specific guidance might be providable.

Comment: Yes, I understand how the $\phi_t$ are defined. But to use the bisection method I must be able to compute them algorithmically. I only have black-box access to the function $f$. Does this make the bisection method not usable? I hope this addresses your point

Comment: How have you established that the black box function is quasi-convex?

Comment: I'm just assuming it's quasi-convex and looking for an algorithm which works in the case that it is quasi-convex and can have arbitrary behaviour otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some differentiability/smoothness requirements for $f$ beyond just quasi-convexity, I'm not sure if there are globally convergent analogs to golden section search. If you are willing to live with the possibility of convergence to a suboptimal point, there is the [Nelder-Mead algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method), which generates a sequence of simplices in a manner similar to how golden section search generates a sequence of intervals. If you do a search on "Nelder-Mead", you will find literature on some variants that, at least in some cases, may come with convergence guarantees when $f$ is sufficiently smooth.